# Show that $\hat{\beta}$ and SSE are independent

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

For a multiple linear regression model y = X$\beta$ + $\epsilon$, the maximum likelihood estimator of $\beta$ and e is noted as $\hat{\beta}$ and e respectively.
Please shows that $\hat{\beta}$ and SSE = $e^T$e are independent.

Comment: This seems a homework-type question. What have you tried?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag.

Comment: The claim is not true in general; it does hold for the normal linear model.

Answer (score 2):

In the classical normal linear regression model (with deterministic regressors) we have $y \sim \mathop{\mathcal N}\left(X\beta, \sigma^2I\right)$.
Consider
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat{\beta}\\
e
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1} X^\top \\
I - X\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1} X^\top
\end{pmatrix}
y
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\mathop{\text{Cov}}\left(\hat\beta, e\right) 
&= 
\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1} X^\top \mathop{\text{Cov}}\left(y,y\right) \left(I - X\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1} X^\top\right)^\top \\
&=
\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1} X^\top \sigma^2 I \left(I - X\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1} X^\top\right)\\
&= 
0.
\end{align}
$$
What does this tell you about $\hat\beta$ and $e$?